# Mock default attribute of SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, testing, flask, sqlalchemy, pytest

I have some issues to mock a SQLAlchemy object when using the `default` and `onupdate` fields in my models :

```
def get_uuid():
    return str(uuid.uuid4())

def get_now():
    return db.func.now()

class BaseModel(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True

    id = db.Column(UUIDType(binary=False), primary_key=True, nullable=False, default=get_uuid)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=get_now(), nullable=False, index=True)
```

The `get_now()` and `get_uuid()` behaviour do not change even when I try to mock them in my tests :

```
def test_create_source(client, mocker):

    mock = mocker.MagicMock(return_value='123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000')
    mocker.patch('myproject.models.get_uuid', mock)
    mock = mocker.MagicMock(return_value=datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1))
    mocker.patch('myproject.models.get_now', mock)

    resp = client.post('/sources', json={'name': 'My source'})
    assert resp.json == {
        'name': 'My source',
        'id': '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000',
        'createdAt': 'Tue, 01 Jan 2019 00:00:00 GMT',
        'updatedAt': 'Tue, 01 Jan 2019 00:00:00 GMT'
    }

### Results :

>       assert resp.json == {
            'name': 'My source',
            'id': '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000',
            'createdAt': 'Tue, 01 Jan 2019 00:00:00 GMT',
            'updatedAt': 'Tue, 01 Jan 2019 00:00:00 GMT'
        }
E       AssertionError: assert {'createdAt':...17:38:38 GMT'} == {'createdAt': ...00:00:00 GMT'}
E         Omitting 1 identical items, use -vv to show
E         Differing items:
E         {'id': '8eb074c0-41e9-436c-8f71-b4c6842f4809'} != {'id': '123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000'}
E         {'createdAt': 'Fri, 18 Jan 2019 17:38:38 GMT'} != {'createdAt': 'Tue, 01 Jan 2019 00:00:00 GMT'}
E         {'updatedAt': 'Fri, 18 Jan 2019 17:38:38 GMT'} != {'updatedAt': 'Tue, 01 Jan 2019 00:00:00 GMT'}
E         Use -v to get the full diff

tests/test_sources.py:17: AssertionError
```

I think it's because my models and its attributes are already imported and evaluated before doing my test, so the mock is useless here. It's explained in the "Mocking class helpers" part of this [post](https://medium.com/@yeraydiazdiaz/what-the-mock-cheatsheet-mocking-in-python-6a71db997832) but I still was not able to fix my issue :(

The full runnable code to reproduce the problem is available here : https://github.com/ncrocfer/flaskmock

Do you have some ideas please ?

Answer (score 0):

> I think it's because my models and its attributes are already imported and evaluated before doing my test, so the mock is useless here.

Close: you've passed a reference to function `get_uuid()` as default to `id` and the result of calling `get_now()` (a function expression object) as default to `created_at`. Changing what those names are bound to in the module after the fact has no effect anymore on the columns, which already hold references to the objects themselves.

In case of `get_uuid()` you should mock the function it is calling:

```
mock = mocker.MagicMock(return_value='123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000')
mocker.patch('uuid.uuid4', mock)
```

and in case of `get_now()` you should consider not calling it during model construction:

```
class BaseModel(db.Model):
    ...
    created_at = db.Column(..., default=get_now, ...)
```

so that you can again mock the actual function it is calling:

```
mock = mocker.MagicMock(return_value=datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1))
mocker.patch('sqlalchemy.func.now', mock)
```

On the other hand perhaps you should not be asserting anything about `id` and the timestamps in the test, since it seems that the important thing is to verify that the name was set correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your answzer and your explanation Ilja ! Your solution works very well for the uuid mock, but SQLAlchemy does not seem to like when I do not call the `get_now` function during the model construction : `sqlalchemy.exc.StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input. [SQL: 'INSERT INTO sources (id, created_at, updated_at, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: [{'name': 'My source'}]]`

Comment: That's an oversight on my part, and a bit trickier to handle. Will have to ponder a bit. It's a result of the default function producing something other than a Python `datetime` during execution (SQLA special cases passing an sql expression object as default during construction, or so).